# macOS 10.13: Entering sleep mode restarts iMac

Tags: imac, sleep-wake, high-sierra, restart

I have a problem on my iMac (late 2013) ever since I installed High Sierra (10.13 - 17A405). When my **iMac goes into sleep** mode because I'm away for too long, or when I manually activate sleep mode (with holding the power button for a few seconds), it always **restarts because of an encountered problem**.

This gets really frustrating since this is my iMac at my work place and it happens multiple times a day. For my work I have a few programs and browser tabs open and it gets really annoying having to "ready" my computer before I can get work done multiple times a day.

For a temporary "solution" I keep my iMac inactive period (before it goes to sleep) really high (on 2 hours or so), so that whenever I leave my work space for appointments it is still on when I come back. But that is no solution and I still get this problem a few times a day

How can I prevent these reboot? I already tried resetting the PRAM, but don't know what to do other than that.

Comment: Try this in Safe Mode or with a different user account.  Set your sleep mode to go into effect sooner so you don't have to wait and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: I know the problem doesn't go away, because I still have it a couple times a day. What do you want me to do in Safe Mode? I will try the different user account, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Operate as you normally would, but in Safe Mode.  Set the sleep timeout for a short duration so you "force" the issue sooner - this is for testing.

Comment: I tried in safe mode, I also set sleep time to 1 minute. It worked a couple of times when I was only a few minutes away (toilet/coffee break). But when I went away for a longer period of time (around 30 minutes) and came back it still had restarted and I was out of the safe mode. Maybe the time I'm away has something to do with the problem?

Comment: Go into the Console (Utilities) and look for anything around the time of the shutdown.  Also look for a phrase that says "shutdown cause"

Comment: Never had this problem before.
Have the same issue with my iMac since upgrade to High Sierra. Machine restarts when it is in sleep randomly.
iCloud and Sharing are off.
Tweaked with Energy Saver options, turned all to OFF,
increased sleep times to 1 for computer sleep 10 mins for display. Still it restarts 2/3 times a day when it randomly
awakens from sleep (not user initiated).

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to answer to Allan. I looked at my console but couldn't find any phrases that had "Shutdown cause" or variations in them. Maybe I didn't look at the right screen? I looked at the devices part in the side column and the reports part.